# Adding foreign keys exceptions caught when loading imdb data to mysql using imdbpy

Tags: python, mysql, imdb, imdbpy

I was trying to load imdb data to mysql database using [IMDBPY 5.1](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/).
But I always encounter the following issues in the end. I need to have the complete primary key + foreign key constraints in the schema. Could anyone give me some hints that what might possible be the cause?

```
building database indexes (this may take a while)
# TIME createIndexes() : 38min, 6sec (wall) 0min, 0sec (user) 0min, 0sec (system)
adding foreign keys (this may take a while)
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_d`, CONSTRAINT `title_episode_of_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`episode_of_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `aka_title_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `cast_info_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `complete_cast_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `movie_keyword_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `movie_link_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `movie_info_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `movie_info_idx_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
ERROR caught exception creating a foreign key: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`imdb`.`#sql-65bf_e`, CONSTRAINT `movie_companies_movie_id_exists` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`id`))
# TIME createForeignKeys() : 655min, 16sec (wall) 0min, 0sec (user) 0min, 0sec (system)
RESTORING imdbIDs values for movies... WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs using the temporary table (falling back to dbm): missing "title_extract" table (ok if this is the first run)
WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs (ok if this is the first run)
RESTORING imdbIDs values for people... WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs using the temporary table (falling back to dbm): missing "name_extract" table (ok if this is the first run)
WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs (ok if this is the first run)
RESTORING imdbIDs values for characters... WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs using the temporary table (falling back to dbm): missing "char_name_extract" table (ok if this is the first run)
WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs (ok if this is the first run)
RESTORING imdbIDs values for companies... WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs using the temporary table (falling back to dbm): missing "company_name_extract" table (ok if this is the first run)
WARNING: unable to restore imdbIDs (ok if this is the first run)
```

The commands I used are as follows

1) Install all the required packages.

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc python python-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python-setuptools python-pip
easy_install -U SQLObject
pip install MySQL-python
```

2) Install IMDBPY.

```
cd [IMDBPY_parent_directory]
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/imdbpy/IMDbPY-5.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf IMDbPY-5.1.tar.gz
cd IMDbPY-5.1
python setup.py install
```

3) In mysql, create a database "imdb", and grant all privileges to "user" with password "password".

```
CREATE DATABASE imdb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON imdb.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

4) Download all IMDB data.

```
mkdir [imdb_data_directory]
cd [imdb_data_directory]
wget -r --accept="*.gz" --no-directories --no-host-directories --level 1 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/
```

5) Load IMDB data to mysql.

```
cd [IMDBPY_parent_directory]/IMDbPY-5.1/bin
python imdbpy2sql.py -d [imdb_data_directory] -u
'mysql://user:password@localhost/imdb'
```

My settings are:

- python: 2.7
- Mysql: 5.7
- Ubuntu 16.04

I also tried on macOS 10.12 + mysql 5.7 + python 2.7 and had the same issue.

**To Davide's suggestions using SQLAlchemy instead of SQLObject:**

I tried sqlalchemy using the following command:

```
python imdbpy2sql.py -d [imdb_file_directory] -o sqlalchemy -u 'mysql://user:password@localhost/imdb?charset=utf8&local_infile=1'
```

I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdbpy2sql.py", line 538, in <module>
    conn = setConnection(URI, DB_TABLES)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IMDbPY-5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/imdb/parser/sql/alchemyadapter.py", line 489, in setConnection
    engine = create_engine(uri, **params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 160, in create
    engineclass.__name__))
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'local_infile' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

I was using sqlalchemy version 1.1.8. I received the same error when I switched to sqlalchemy version 0.5. And when I switched to sqlalchemy 0.4, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdbpy2sql.py", line 323, in <module>
    from imdb.parser.sql.alchemyadapter import getDBTables, setConnection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IMDbPY-5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/imdb/parser/sql/alchemyadapter.py", line 54, in <module>
    UNICODECOL: UnicodeText,
NameError: name 'UnicodeText' is not defined
```

Did I specify 'local_infile' wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it's most probably a bug in the code.

As a workaround, try using SQLAlchemy instead of SQLObject.
Try installing it and using it adding "-o sqlalchemy" (no quotes) to the command line options of imdbpy2sql.py.